# In jQuery, I used ajax to call api in codeigniter for search user but respose does not show

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function laod_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://dev.theoneinfotech.com/user/usersearch",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          search_string: query,
          data: {
            search_string: query, 
            access_token: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('access_token')?>'
          },
          success : function(resp) {
            alert(resp);
            $('#response_data').html(resp);
          }
        });
    }
    $('#field2').keyup(function() {
      var search = $(this).val();
      if (search != '') {
        laod_data(search);
      } else {
        laod_data();
      }
    });
  });
```

API receive 2 input

1. access_token.
2. search_string.

Here i want to show result that appears according to entering data on search box.
please help me, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks a lot, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing up with single quotes.

In Javascript, if a string starts with single quote, it looks for next single quote (if not escaped) as its end.

In your case, it is getting at

```
'<?php echo $this->session->userdata('
```

Which is incorrect.

Therefore, javascript is breaking.

Please change

```
access_token: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('access_token')?>'
```

To

```
access_token: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata("access_token")?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX Syntax is incorrect. You have incorrectly added the success function to the data field/param of the AJAX call. And you're also messing up the php quotes as @Pupil pointed out.

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://dev.theoneinfotech.com/user/usersearch",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    search_string: query,
    data: {
      search_string: query, 
      access_token: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('access_token')?>'
    }
  },
  success : function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
    $('#response_data').html(resp);
  });
}
```